# How to get font information or view a document of a Word 2003 .doc file?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I've just received a file containing text in hindi language. The document was created using a font installed on the document-creator's PC. So I don't have the language font installed on my system. 
I open the sent_file.doc in my word 2010, and it shows garbage text with no meaning or formatting. I tried looking online for a solution of how to find the font or the font name, but couldn't find anything.

I just need a printout of the document. Please can someone provide any help?

Thanks.

Comment: quickest solution might be requesting the file as pdf from the sender

Comment: Well, I asked the sender for the font name. He replied it was devnagri.... Then I searched for devanagri and found atleast 500 different types of devanagri fonts listed on the devanagri website. So I downloaded 2 of the popular types, and installed them temporarily. Opened the document.doc and still garbage text was showing. Then I glanced at the font word was using to display the document, and noticed that it wasn't the ones I had downloaded: Kruti010. So I searched google again for the particular Kruti010 and found it. Installed it [temporarily](http://goo.gl/O95a7), and problem solved!! :D

Comment: you can post your solution as reply then accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem was solved in a simple way..

1. I asked the sender for the font name. He replied it was devnagri....
2. Then I searched for devanagri and found atleast 500 different types of devanagri fonts listed on the devanagri website.
3. So I downloaded 2 of the popular types, and installed them [temporarily](http://goo.gl/O95a7).
4. Opened the document.doc and still garbage text was showing.
5. **Then I glanced at the font word was using to display the document, and noticed that it wasn't the ones I had downloaded: Kruti010.**
6. So I searched google again for the particular Kruti010 and found it.
7. Installed it [temporarily](http://goo.gl/O95a7), and problem solved!!